# Alternative of Microsoft Visio?

Tags: applications, software-recommendation

I am looking for a good alternative of Microsoft Visio for Mac OS X.
I need an application to create a schedule of the month or something like this and then to print it.

Comment: Tricky, hard to say what "good" might entail.  If I was making a schedule, I would never consider using Visio.  Word or Excel perhaps, but not Visio.  Can you clarify your requirements a little more?

Comment: Ya I need an application that will choose a month of the year and then to be able to add to-do things in each date and to be in a printable form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can use Visio for this sort of thing, it's not really ideal.  One method is to use the normal Calendar App, but it might be hard to get it to print how  you like it.

Another is to use something like *Numbers* from the *iWork* suite.  It has several templates that you can use for creating planners (daily/weekly/monthly), and while some may need customising toe be exactly what you need, you will only need to do it once, then re-save the template to use again.  Here are some screenshots of standard templates with the latest version of *Numbers*:

[image: Weekly]

[image: Daily]

[image: Monthly]

Answer (score 2):

I recommend OmniGraffle Pro (http://www.omnigroup.com/omniGraffle) from the Omni Group.  They have a standard and pro version.  You can download trial version of either the standard or pro version.

Comment: Please add you can download templates /stencils of almost everything you can think of. The program is great!

Comment: thanks I will download this one and I will test it. But until I find the @stuffe solution good I mark stuffe's solution as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget that Google Drive has a new Web-based App that will let you edit/import/export Visio documents -- its called Lucid Diagram.

There is a free account and a pro verion:

Limits on free account: 
-60 Objects per document 
-Can publish to web/pdf/png/jpeg 
-No wireframing or mockups 
-No revision history 
-No Visio Import/Export capabilities 
-Limit of 2 collaborators per document Here is a link to our pricing page with a list of levels and features https://www.lucidchart.com/users/registerLevel

Currently there is a 14 day free pro trial.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try [Edraw Max - A nice Visio replacement](https://www.edrawsoft.com/visio-alternative.php) that includes the Calendar drawing suite you want.

I like the appearance of its interface. Not much too learn, no difficult commands.

It could import/export Visio files. Easy to pulish to PDF, Word, JPEG, PNG, Html, SVG, etc.
[image]